# Grouping values in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of size a*2. (Typical size of a is 100). In the first column are values between x_smallest and x_largest. In the second column are the corresponding y values. Now almost all x values are unique, so I want to group them. Like the first group goes from values x_smallest to x_1. The second group from x_1 to x_2. (x_smallest < x_1 < ... x_largest). This should be adjustable, so that I can find a useful size. I should mention that the x values are Not integers, but the y values are integers. (The y values are between 1 and N) Now I would like to know for each group the proportion of "n>1" y values against the "1" y values. Here is a small fraction of an example array:

```
2.750000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+00
3.100000000000000089e+00,5.000000000000000000e+00
2.649999999999999911e+00,2.000000000000000000e+00
2.500000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+00
3.100000000000000089e+00,2.000000000000000000e+00
2.799999999999999822e+00,5.000000000000000000e+00
3.450000000000000178e+00,4.000000000000000000e+00
3.200000000000000178e+00,5.000000000000000000e+00
3.200000000000000178e+00,3.000000000000000000e+00
2.399999999999999911e+00,1.000000000000000000e+00
```

The output array could look like this:

```
1.5, 0
2.5, 0.2
3.5, 0.5
```

(Here the x_values are the midpoint of the area of x_i and x_i+1. )The output example here clearly doesn't fit to the example array. Do you have any ideas how this can be done easily. I could only think about making many specific if else commands which wouldn't be very helpful for general cases.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"the proportion of "n>1" y values against the "1" y values."* Can you give a matching example of input and output? *"I could only think about making many specific if else commands"* - could you show us what that code would look like?

Comment: The y values are integers. So for a specific group of x values I could have the following y values `[1,1,2,2,4,5]` (if it is sorted). Now the proportion that I mean ist `4/2` because there are `4` values larger then 1 and `2` values have value 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I solved it by myself. Here is the solution in case someone has a similiar problem and finds this question:

```
numgroup = 5  # Number of Groups
dmimax = numpy.amax(dmivsstasta[:, 0])  # Gets x_largest
dmimin = numpy.amin(dmivsstasta[:, 0])  # Gets x_smallest
stamax = numpy.amax(dmivsstasta[:, 1])  # Gets y_largest
stepsize = (dmimax-dmimin)/5.0  # Determines size of a group

grouparray = numpy.zeros((5, stamax+1)) # Creates array in which everything is saved


for x in range(numgroup):
    grouparray[x, 0] = dmimin+stepsize/2.0+x*stepsize  # Saves midpositon of 
                                                         each group at first column
print(grouparray)  # Just to check values
print(dmimin)
print(dmimax)
print(stepsize)

for x1 in range(numgroup):  # Iterates over all values
    for x2 in range(rd):
        if (grouparray[x1, 0]-stepsize/2.0) <= dmivsstasta[x2, 0] 
        < (grouparray[x1, 0]+stepsize/2.0):
            grouparray[x1, dmivsstasta[x2, 1]] += 1

print(grouparray)
```

The only missing part is to calculate the proportion, which is now easy to do with the grouparray